# $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problems in graph theory: undirected vs. directed

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np

Is it true that it is much easier to establish $\mathrm{NP}$-complete on undirected graphs than digraphs (directed graph)?

Academic articles proving $\mathrm{NP}$-completeness of problems on undirected graphs are outnumbering those on digraphs.

Comment: You could also compare the number of papers on undirected graphs with those on directed graphs.

Comment: No stats, but examples. [Graph problems which are NP-Complete on directed graphs but polynomial on undirected graphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20989/337) for several examples of the opposite. And [“Directed” problems that are easier than their “undirected” variant](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9257/337) for the direction you seek.

Comment: I’d say it’s rather the opposite: NP-completeness results for undirected graphs are more *difficult* to establish, and therefore more interesting. Graph theorists are more interested in undirected graphs than directed graphs anyway. Any problem on undirected graphs can be trivially restated as a problem on directed graphs, if it comes to it.